# Java. Method Inner Object as return type

Tags: java, class, object, theory, scjp

Can I return method local inner object from method?

```
public class myClass {
    public MyMethodInnerClass getMethodInnerClassObject() {
        class MyMethodInnerClass {
        }
        
        MyMethodInnerClass myMethodClass = new MyMethodInnerClass();
        
        return myMethodClass;
    }
}
```

throws compilation error.
If I can't return my method-local inner class object, then how can I save it after the method returns?
How can I reference this object for future usage?

---

Exception thrown:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:
MethodInnerClass cannot be resolved to a type

And also, I'm aware, that local variables in method are stored in stack and deleted just after the method exists.

Comment: what is the compilation error? kindly post it

Comment: You can't. Don't design it this way. The class `MyMethodInnerClass` is a local class. Its scope is only the body of the method.

Comment: I don't have a Java compiler right one. Is it even possible to declare a class in a method ?

Comment: @Dici it is but it is also very rarely used.

Comment: @PeterLawrey ok, thanks. Does not really make sense to me. You cannot define a method in a method, but a class in a method is fine. Hum...

Comment: @dici https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/localclasses.html

Comment: @Dici added exception text, you asked

Comment: @Dici You can't define an interface, enum or annotation.

Comment: Ok thanks to both of you :p

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The scope of your class is inside the method only.  You can do this however

```
public Object getMethodInnerClassObject() {
```

or

```
static class MyMethodInnerClass { }

public MyMethodInnerClass getMethodInnerClassObject() {
    return new MyMethodInnerClass();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I know it's a bad design. But just for fun, you can use this object outside the method using reflection.

```
public class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Outer o = new Outer();
        Outer.Inner in = o.new Inner();
        //method local object
        Object localObj = in.printInner();
        //abusing reflection
        localObj.getClass().getMethods()[0].invoke(localObj);
    }
}

class Outer {
    class Inner{
        
        Object printInner() {
            class LocalInner {
                public void printLocal() {
                    System.out.println("Inside local inner... :P");
                }
            }
            return new LocalInner();
        }
    }
}
```

This prints:

> Inside local inner... :P